# Connecting an 18AWG wire to a 20AWG wire

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have some equipment that is powered by an AC/DC power plug. The plug input is 100-240V - 50/60Hz 0.8A. The output is 12V 2A.

The wire for the plug is a bit short, so I want to extend its reach. I found a power adapter extension that connects properly (2.1mm x 5.5mm, Male to Female) (it's here: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00FTFYH0U/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FTFYH0U)).

However, this extension uses UL2468 / 20AWG while the cord coming out of the AC/DC power plug is 18AWG. Can I safely use the power adapter extension with this AC/DC power plug, or do I risk damaging the equipment?

Comment: Chances are yes, but tell us the voltage and amperage coming out of the transformer.

Comment: I very seriously doubt this represents and problem, however we need to know the voltage delivered by the transformer and the wattage required by the load, to know for sure.

Comment: @PaulLogan  The linked product specifies "Recommended up to 36 volt, max load 3 amp or less." [sic] which gives us some idea, assuming OP got that much right.  Even at max current (3A), the 20 AWG would probably handle at least twice the amps specified on that product, but one does have to wonder why the product engineer spec'd a unit with 18 AWG wire originally (convenience, compatibility, safety margin...).

Comment: I think I've added the information you needed to help me confirm if this is okay.

Comment: @ upnorth, I suspect that that was the unit readily available and because of volume production, most economical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwj4-Ob9-ObXAhWm0YMKHSqeDdoQFgg7MAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hca.hitachi-cable.com%2Fproducts%2Fhca%2Ffaq%2Fdata%2FCurrent-Carrying-Capacity_Jan2012.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2QKCbUR4y_A9NjoP9hhsP1) is a link to a table that shows #20 AWG wire is good for 10 amps at 30ºC.

I am pretty sure you will be just fine.

Good luck!